# Insert a skak symbol

Tags: symbols, lyx, skak

I'm trying to enter a chess symbols of *skak* package, and output it at **pdflatex** but it didn't compile...(at Lyx).

What can I do?
I enter it at math mode.
(there is no other way).

(Idon't know what is xskak and if it would help...)

Here is the error code:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file SkakNew-Figurine): Font SkakNew-Figurine at 600 n
```

Here is the code:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[twocolumn,english,hebrew]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
      \hb@xt@\textwidth {%
      \kern\textwidth \kern-\columnwidth %**
      \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
         \box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
      \kern-\textwidth %**
      \hfil
      {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
      \hfil
      \kern-\textwidth  %**
      \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
         \box\@outputbox \hss}%
      \kern-\columnwidth \kern\textwidth %**
    }%
  }%
  \@combinedblfloats
  \@outputpage
  \begingroup
  \@dblfloatplacement
  \@startdblcolumn
  \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
  {\@outputpage
    \@startdblcolumn}%
  \endgroup
  \fi
}
\@mparswitchtrue

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{skak}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\L{$\Omega=\left\{ \symking,\sympawn\right\} $}

שלום!
\end{document}
```

Hope it's OK and this is what you mean...(you can edit if you want).

Comment: chess symbols are not entered in math mode. Beside this: without some informations why it doesn't compile (log-file) and what code you actually used it is impossible to help you.

Comment: If you want to put some TeX commands directly into the LyX document then you can use ERT / TeX code (CRTL + L).

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work...
I'm writing the document at Hebrew (this is why I need pdflatex).

Comment: **I can enter the symbols only at math mode...**

Comment: I added the error code...

Comment: Add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Yes please add both a minimal example .lyx file and .tex file. For more information on a .lyx minimal example, see here: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Looks as if you haven't activate the map file. Perhaps (!) you need to run updmap on the command line.

Comment: To clarify the "perhaps" in my previous comment: If you have miktex and a multiuser installation then the most probable cause of your problem is that you need to update your user map files by running (as user) on the command line `updmap`. To enter chess symbols in math mode is not necessary but it should work and so is a workaround if Lyx won't let you insert them in text mode.

Comment: Thank you! but how I put the `updmap`? i.e. where should I run it?

Comment: For me, it is necessary that the package [`skaknew`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/skaknew) is installed but I do *not* use it (just the normal `\usepackage{skak}`). Furthermore, in my home directory I deleted the directory ".texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/" with all subdirectories (the exact location might be a bit different on your system).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you make your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you have miktex and a multiuser installation then the most probable cause of your problem is that you need to update your user map files by running (as user) on the command line updmap to activate the map file. To enter chess symbols in math mode is not necessary but it should work and so is a workaround if Lyx won't let you insert them in text mode